Schema.org > Product > Offer for a specific quantity of items (with limited availability)?
How to specify a Schema.org > Product > Offer for a specific quantity of items (with limited availability)?
Is example usage below of referenceQuantity & eligibleQuantity correct or are there other more suitable options?
Situation 1: 6 chairs available, listed price if for the 6 chairs together
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Set of 6 Vintage lounge seats",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/12345/",
  "description": "For sale, set of 6 used lounge seats",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceSpecification": {
      "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification",
      "price": "1250",
      "priceCurrency": "EUR",
      "referenceQuantity": {
        "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
        "value": "6"
      },
      "eligibleQuantity": {
        "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
        "value": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}

Situation 2: 6 chairs available, listed price if for the 1 chair
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "6 Vintage lounge seats",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/12345/",
  "description": "For sale, 6 used lounge seats",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceSpecification": {
      "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification",
      "price": "250",
      "priceCurrency": "EUR",
      "referenceQuantity": {
        "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
        "value": "1"
      },
      "eligibleQuantity": {
        "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
        "value": "6"
      }
    }
  }
}


You'll need to combine these. One is about a single item (price 250E); another is about all items (price 1250E). But you cannot read, in a single structure, that the unit price is 250E, but if you buy six at one time the price is 1250E. Therefore, you need two conditions in your graph: the price for one; the price for six.

In the first situation only 1 set of 6 chairs is available (cannot be bought separately), in the second situation there are 6 separate pieces which can be bought a piece or in multiple quantities (all at the same item price, no discounts). Not sure if eligibleQuantity can be used to specify the total available mentioned in referenceQuantity.

Google also wants unitCode and a valueReference when you use referenceQuantity.  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/merchant-listing#unit-pricing-quantitative-value-properties
